# date - how to get next weekday (ignore weekends)

Tags: date

I'm setting up a cron job to suspend and wake a server at certian times.

I'm using two commands. One to be run from mondays to thursdays:

```
rtcwake -m mem -t $(date +%s -d "08:00")
```

And another one to be run on fridays:

```
rtcwake -m mem -t $(date +%s -d "monday 08:00")
```

I wonder if it's possible to make this separation unnecessary. If `date` could understand a statement like `next weekday 08:00`, it'd simplify things a lot.

I wasn't able to find if this is actually possible or what syntax should I use.

I basically want to avoid my server waking up on saturdays and sundays.

Comment: Have you considered having two separate cron jobs?

Comment: Note - the week start day varies by locale.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `ksh93`, you can easily calculate "next weekday 0800", which I assume really means first business day of the next week. Assuming you are located in the USA, the first business day of the week is typically a Monday.

```
$ printf "%T\n"                
Tue Jan  5 16:04:37 GMT 2021
$ printf "%T\n" "0 8 * * 1"
Mon Jan 11 08:00:00 GMT 2021
$ printf "%(%s)T\n" "0 8 * * 1"
1610352000
$
```

The key to how the above works is the string `"0 8 * * 1"` which is represents the five `crontab` time and date fields. See `crontab(5)` manpage for details of these fields.

Not many people are aware that `ksh93` time formatting recognizes specific parts of this quasi-crontab entry format, and outputs the corresponding date in the designated format.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
date +%s -d"$(( ( $(date +%w)==5 )?3:1 ))days 8:00"
```

**EDIT:** to answer your comment:
`date +%w` yields the day of week, which then is evaluated by a "conditional operator" (`expr?expr:expr`): if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, evaluate and use expr2, else expr3. So, on Friday, we have day 5, and run `date +%s -d"3days 8:00`, on the other days `date +%s -d"1days 8:00`.

Comment: Note that in a cron job specification, the `%` character has to be escaped as `\%`.

Comment: Hmm - yes, thanks - but not in his/her question above...

Comment: "I'm setting up a cron job"...

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a bit how does this code work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with for a similar need.  Way more verbose than the other answer but it may make it a bit more obvious what it's doing.

```
last_workday() {
    from_date="${@:-today}"
    day_of_week=$(date +%w --date="${from_date}")

    if [ ${day_of_week} = "0" ] ; then
        look_back=2
    elif [ ${day_of_week} = "1" ] ; then
        look_back=3
    else
        look_back=1
    fi

    date -d "${from_date} - ${look_back} day" +'%Y/%m/%d'
}

next_workday() {
    from_date="${@:-today}"
    day_of_week=$(date +%w --date="${from_date}")
    if [ ${day_of_week} = "5" ] ; then
        look_forward=3
    elif [ ${day_of_week} = "6" ] ; then
        look_forward=2
    else
        look_back=1
    fi

    date -d "${from_date} + ${look_forward} day" +'%Y/%m/%d'
}

for i in $(seq 16); do
    now=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d' --date="today + ${i} day")
    prev=$(last_workday "${now}")
    next=$(next_workday "${now}")
    echo "${now}:  ${prev} ${next}"
done
```